# replace all spaces and colons in a data.table with underscore r

Tags: regex, r, string, data.table

I have a 467,000 by 8000 data.table .

I would like to replace all colons and white spaces with an underscore. For every row and column in the data.table.

Instead of

```
Assignment 5: Constitutional Law

Assignment_5__Constitutional_Law
```

My data includes date, numeric and character variables.

```
library(data.table)
sample<-data.table(STUDENT_ID = c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5"), Duedate=c("2015-07-29 08:00", "2015-08-05 08:00","2015-08-12 08:00", "2015-08-19 08:00", "2015-08-26 08:00"),Assignment=c(rep("Assignment 1: Physics",5)), GRADE = c(70:74))
sample$Duedate <- as.Date(sample$Duedate,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

Comment: If the columns are all character or factor variables, try `dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) gsub("\\s", "_", x))]`. We can be more sure if you added an example data table that looks similar to your data.

Comment: And what have you tried? I assume you should be able to just run `gsub` over each column using `:=` - something like `DT[, (names(DT)) := lapply(.SD, gsub, pattern="[: ]", replacement="_")]`

Answer (score 2):

Find the character variables and then replace them by reference:

```
charvars <- sapply(sample,is.character)
sample[,
       (names(sample)[charvars]) := lapply(.SD, gsub, pat="[: ]", rep="_"),
       .SDcols=charvars
      ]
sample

#   STUDENT_ID    Duedate            Assignment GRADE
#1:         A1 2015-07-29 Assignment_1__Physics    70
#2:         A2 2015-08-05 Assignment_1__Physics    71
#3:         A3 2015-08-12 Assignment_1__Physics    72
#4:         A4 2015-08-19 Assignment_1__Physics    73
#5:         A5 2015-08-26 Assignment_1__Physics    74
```